# Is explicit whitelisting possible in Apache Struts 1.1?

Tags: java, struts-1

I am doing some work on a legacy application that uses apache struts 1.1

Is there a way to enforce explicit whitelisting of formfields in an action class, similar to this (from ASP .NET):

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PropertyToInclude1, PropertyToInclude2")] Employee employee) {

    //action code here

}
```

Comment: Normally the `ActionForm` would only include fields you want. You could write a custom request processor that strips out un-wanted parameters, but that's not on a per-action basis. What's your usecase?

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of a mass assignment vulnerability: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mass_Assignment_Cheat_Sheet

In the past I've used whitelisting to protect sensitive attributes. But that may not be necessary in this case, if I just don't include sensitive fields in the action form?

Comment: As a follow up, I know that there are cases where an attribute must be in the action form, but I don't want it to always be accessible. I guess that could be handled with a form validation function?

Comment: If it shouldn't be "accessible" (not sure what that means in this case) then it probably shouldn't be in that particular `ActionForm`. You *could* re-use forms by making them context-sensitive, IMO that's more trouble than it's worth. If it's based on user-role, e.g., something visible (and immutable) on the server side, it's not awful, but then you have to test your forms more extensively.